# How to get the size of activity stack?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to get the current size of the activity stack for debugging, is there any to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do it from the device (that I'm aware of), but if it's for debugging there's always `dumpsys activity` which you can call from the adb shell, or, for a one-off at the command-line, just `adb shell dumpsys activity`